# Local maxima anomalies of likelihood methods

Tags: maximum-likelihood, method-of-moments

Likelihood methods have many desired properties. Sadly, local maxima in finite samples is not one of them. The fact a local maximum exists near the true parameter value is of no comfort if one converges to different local maxima.

I am looking for works reviewing this problem, demonstrating it, and offering solutions.

Comment: John, are you asking about works discussing, say, which *models* may have multiple local maxima or is your question about *optimization methods* and the risk that they might return maxima that are global but not local?

Comment: @whuber: I would like examples of models which generate the problem. As for the solutions- I would like estimation methods other than maximum-likelihood.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand your question, John, and that includes understanding more precisely what the *problem* itself is. As far as methods other than ML, there are entire multi-volume books written on this topic, so some clearer guidance about that is needed, too.

Comment: @whuber: OK- the problem I have is that while the likelihood might have one asymptotic maximum, in a finite sample it will have many local maxima. Some of them (I believe) might be far from the true parameter value. A possible solution is to look for the global maximum. Does this approach have any theoretical justification? Put differently- is there any guarantee the global maximum has lower MSE then any other local maxima? If not, might there be some other estimation method with better performance?

Comment: Where I'm confused is that ML does *not* say to find just any local maximum: it says to find a *global* maximum. It will--obviously--run into trouble when there exist multiple distinct global maxima, but that's not what you have been asking about here. Further, ML has *nothing* to do with mean squared errors. (That there happens to be a connection with MSE in a regression context through the Gauss-Markov theorem is a useful fact but is not an inherent general property of ML.) Depending on how you measure "performance," there are *loads* of better methods--answering that takes a huge book.

Comment: @whuber: The sequence of roots of the score function converging to the true parameter value, need not be the sequence corresponding to the (finite sample) *global* maximum. It is true that in the "nice" cases, there is a unique sequence so the issue does not arise (Theory of Point Estimation, p.445, Corollary 3.5). But in other cases, I believe the "best" (in MSE or any other sense) estimator might be a local maximum and not a global one. It is these cases I am interested in.

Comment: With this most recent comment, John, your question appears to have changed once again, because it seems to be concerned with *asymptotic* behavior of solutions.  The second part of your comment is opaque to me, because the "local maximum" language is particular to ML and does not apply to most other estimators.

Comment: @whuber: I do not believe this is another question. I was just trying to demonstrate that in finite samples, the global maximum need not be the best estimate (at least that is how I understand the reference I proposed).

Comment: I think you are confusing "best estimate" with "true value," John. This seems to be the difficulty @AdamO was trying to address, also.

Answer (score 4):

As Cagdas Ozgenc points out in his answer, there is a simple sufficient condition to render this question moot: that the likelihood be concave in the parameter space (almost surely with respect to the sampling distribution of the data).  That does cover many interesting cases (ie, the exponential family), but basically leaves everything else out.

I don't have an answer here, but think that there are several ways this question could be refined or restated:

1. What properties does the MLE have in finite samples, and under what models?  Although everyone likes the MLE, it's usage (AFAIK) is predicated on asymptotic guarantees.  I can't think of any finite sample guarantees for it.
2. What properties, if any, does a local maxima have?

### Bibliography

"Evaluation of the Maximum-Likelihood Estimator where the Likelihood Equation has Multiple Roots" VD Barnette 1966.
**The Cauchy distribution with location parameter offers a canonical example of a likelihood with multiple roots (even asymptotically).**

["Testing for a Global Maximum of the Likelihood"](http://math.univ-lille1.fr/~biernack/index_files/testML_full_version.pdf) Christophe Biernacki, 2005.
**A test for consistency for a root of the likelihood equation, based on comparing the observed maximized likelihood to its expected value under the putative argmax**

["Eliminating Multiple Root Problems in Estimation"](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ss/1009213001) Small, Wang, Yang 2000.
**If you are going to read one paper, this is probably it.  Discusses all of the above, also in the context of generalized estimating equations, plus suggests smoothing or penalizing the likelihood to help resolve multiple roots.**

Answer (score 1):

No estimator will converge in probability to the parameter value in finite samples due to the random nature of data in general. Maximum likelihood estimators are consistent and efficient among unbiased estimators of parameter values. In fact, MLEs are root-n consistent by the CLT, meaning that they converge to the parameter value as the sample size increases considerable faster than any other general unbiased estimator (in most cases) including method of moments. Simply put, in correct specifications of probability models for data generating mechanisms, MLE is one of the best tools around. If you're looking for a general probability theory text dealing with asymptotic estimation, I'd refer you to Lehmann & Casella's Theory of Point Estimation.

Comment: MLEs obviously have many good asymptotic properties. It is the multiple local maxima in finite samples that bothers me and you did not adress this in your reply.

Comment: MLEs *converge* to unique solutions in the long run. Do you not see how in finite samples the likelihood function varies with respect to the observed data to produce many local maxima? This is trivial. It would be impossible to produce estimators with any desirable properties that didn't have that feature.

Comment: In most classical cases (say, the exponential family), the likelihood has a single local maximum. This is not the case for more complicated models.

Comment: A slightly different problem is with unbounded likelihoods: https://xianblog.wordpress.com/2015/04/02/the-unbounded-likelihood-problem/   and   https://doi.org/10.1080/00031305.2014.1003968

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue of finite samples. It is related to the complexity of the combined error function and the link function. As long as it is quadratic there won't be multiple maxima. If not you will most likely get more than one. For example if you are hypothesizing that the data has a normal distribution then you have:

$N(f(y|x;\theta),\sigma)$

where f is the link function. Now if you consider the pdf:

$f(y) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{1/2}\sigma} e^{-\frac{(y-f(x;\theta))^2}{2\sigma^2}}$

The combined function, link function plugged into the distribution, in this scenario is quadratic (don't worry about the exponential as it disappears when you work with its logarithm) if $f(y|x;\theta)$ is a linear function. This happens in linear regression with Gaussian errors for example.

In any case if your distribution doesn't have a quadratic form or when combined with the link function ends up non-quadratic you will have the problem of multiple maxima.

There is no good solution to the problem as finding global maximum is NP-hard.

http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~rsw/lgopt.pdf

pages 20-21

There are algorithms that attempt to cover the entire parameter space, but they are very slow as one expects. So it is not an issue of MLE either. If you plug the Likelihood function to a more sophisticated optimizer like simulated annealing, it will search for the global solution.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing

Comment: Is there any reason to prefer the global maximum over a local maximum in finite samples?

Comment: There is some misinformation in this reply.  Among the problems are (1) non-quadratic objective functions can have unique global maxima and even may have no other local maxima; (2) The reference to NP-hard is irrelevant (and potentially confusing or misleading) because "this problem" has not even been defined and it's definitely not true that all nonlinear programs involving non-convex functions are NP-hard.

Comment: @whuber: I didn't say what you claim I said. I said for most of the non-quadratic cases you will have local maxima problem. Of course there are cases where you get unique global maximum when not-quadratic. But in real world most of the time you get stuck in local maxima. In general you have problem of not reading questions properly and bulking at people with comments. You are doing the same to my questions. Sometimes people don't have the basic knowledge to phrase the problems properly. And I understand them because I find myself in such situations most of the time.

Comment: @JohnRos: Of course you should pick the global maximum. That is the objective of the maximization process. The find the best, not the second best. But in real life sometimes you work with what you get.

Comment: I write comments in my role as moderator: where there is some potential for posts to be misinterpreted, my job is to point that out and request clarification. Of course my interpretation could be incorrect, but the important message is that miscommunication is happening. Instead of accusing your readers of ill will or stupidity, please bear in mind that good communication requires honest effort by *both* parties and try to use what I have written to improve your post.

Comment: There was no mention of stupidity, or implied whatsoever. You are being demagogical. Being a moderator doesn't give you the right to treat people disrespectfully. In this case you are doing it by using the word "stupid" as if I had ever used or implied it. That's either demogogy or slander.

Comment: When you think someone is being disrespectful, demagogic, slanderous (which is impossible in a written medium, but never mind), or worse, then please make use of the site's mechanisms for addressing such behavior. Begin by flagging the offending post for moderator attention. If you distrust the moderation (as you seem to), then you can escalate it by a chat, a meta discussion, or by contacting the SE team with a complaint. In the meantime, you have now twice attempted to deflect this conversation from its original point: if you wish to continue commenting, please focus on improving your post.

Comment: Excuse me. I never used the word "stupid" but you claimed that I did. It is a lie and you should apologize for it. Being a moderator doesn't give you such rights.